# Xamarin IOS how to create a Stroy Board from exisitng files?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I found this navigation bar that i want to use but a Cant seem to find the story board for it? or am i looking in the wrong place, How would i generate a story board for it?

here is the link to the bar: `https://components.xamarin.com/view/flyoutnavigation`

Answer (score 0):

You don't generate a storyboard for it. You put a generic view into your storyboard and set it's class to be a custom subclass of `FlyoutNavigationController`, and set it as the root view. You can then grab all of the ViewControllers that are controlled by the `FlyoutNavigationController` by using something similar to the following Objective-C code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
```

or, in C#

```
UIStoryboard sb = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", null);
UIViewController vc = sb.InstantiateViewController("myViewController");
```

Here's the link for storyboarding

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards/